# Run a local python script that connects to a created VM in Google cloud platform to do some AI tasks and save output to bucket for local download

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I have set up a bucket in GCP and can run a local script that can access this via API JSON key and uploads my file of interest. I am now struggling to connect to my VM instance with the local script in order to work on this file to perform image segmentation and then save some output nifti files to bucket again. I need help understanding if its possible to do this with a local script on my computer and how? the plan is to connect to my VM instance, import a nifti file, locate the file in bucket and perform segmentation on it and then save output nifti files back to bucket for local download.

I have tried inside a local venc using jupyter to connect to my VM using import paramiko but no success!

I don't really know what to do from here and if its even possible? I can't find clear examples. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are other services that Google Cloud Platform offers which are less complicated than the process you are referring to.

You can use the Cloud Vision API to perform Optical Character Recognition(OCR), image detection and labelling. You can try this [Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-vision-api-python#0) activity for familiarity.

You can also send requests of large image data to the API via python from local. Make sure to download Cloud SDK along with gsutil, set the configuration, upload images to Google Cloud Storage, then get the labels of images from the bucket. Batch processing is also available for multiple images which is limited to 16 images per batch.

You can refer to this [documentation](https://towardsdatascience.com/google-vision-api-for-image-analysis-with-python-d3a2e45913d4) for the process and the sample code.

[Cloud TPU](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/whats-in-an-image-fast-accurate-image-segmentation-with-cloud-tpus) can also be used in image segmentation since it is optimized to process large matrix calculations.